# Unable to print out correct CUDA matrix addition result

Tags: memory, matrix, cuda, addition

I am trying to add two matrices using blocks and threads in parallel but I am not getting the correct resultant matrix to print out. I think I am having trouble communicating to the device from the host and vice versa.

this is the output I'm getting. The resultant matrix is messed up.

matrix a: 
18   27   48   28   6   16   40   15   30   41
         30   15   25   24   8   0   7   18   7   23
         0   15   47   13   26   16   6   17   39   30
         6   25   11   22   44   34   37   38   31   15
         8   16   17   0   29   6   13   3   30   46
         24   21   30   48   15   23   47   41   26   21
         25   45   14   15   27   20   44   14   7   39
         28   49   3   40   35   40   45   0   37   5
         31   17   24   1   48   6   6   2   46   42
         10   43   20   17   14   23   2   21   26   8

matrix b: 
44   40   26   14   2   49   6   20   46   36
         0   9   5   46   13   26   29   7   46   13
         39   41   30   28   4   6   34   32   43   47
         30   15   46   19   46   45   49   35   1   8
         31   16   36   7   31   38   34   25   26   24
         30   11   11   13   13   25   40   14   42   7
         30   40   49   44   13   1   44   26   13   22
         13   25   41   31   13   10   36   9   18   14
         28   25   33   31   41   27   5   11   44   31
         32   5   44   7   22   45   42   26   24   24

The resultants matrix:

400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496
400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496
400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496 400848496

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 10
#define BLOCK_DIM 5

__global__ void matrixAdd (int *a, int *b, int *c);
int main() {

 int a[N][N], b[N][N], c[N][N];
 int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;
 int size = N * N * sizeof(int);
 time_t t;

 //initialize rand function
 srand((unsigned) time(&t));

// initialize a and b with values 

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++ )
    {
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            a[i][j]= rand() % 50;
            b[i][j]= rand() % 50;
        }
    }
// print matrix a   
    printf("matrix a: ");
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
     printf("\n\t ");
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            printf("%d   ", a[i][j]);
        }
    printf(" ");
    }

    printf("\n ");
//print matrix b    
    printf("matrix b: ");
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
     printf("\n\t ");
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            printf("%d   ", b[i][j]);
        }
    printf(" ");
    }

    printf("\n ");

//allocate memory
 cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size);
 cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, size);
 cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, size);

 cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

 dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_DIM, BLOCK_DIM);
 dim3 dimGrid((int)ceil(N/dimBlock.x),(int)ceil(N/dimBlock.y));

 matrixAdd<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(dev_a,dev_b,dev_c);
 /// __syncthreads(); function call from host not allowed
 cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

// print matrix c   

printf("The resultants matrix: \n");
// print matrix c   

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
     printf("\n\t ");
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", c);
        }
    printf(" ");
    }

    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    cudaFree(dev_c);

 return 0;

}

__global__ void matrixAdd (int *a, int *b, int *c) {

 int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
 int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
 int index = col + row * N;

    if (col < N && row < N) 
    {
        c[index] = a[index] + b[index];
    }
     __syncthreads();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your final output `printf` statement.  This:

```
printf("%d ", c);
```

should be this:

```
printf("%d ", c[i][j]);
```

(which is consistent with your previous `printf` statements)

FWIW, the final `__syncthreads()` statement in your kernel serves no purpose.

Comment: I made the changes but im still not getting the right values for resultant array. just a bunch of random sign ints like                                  -650801528 10967 1031850590 55 1 32767 1034029464 55 0 0  
         0 0 1059089896 55 1031850357 55 -650802768 10967 -653971456 10967  
         1034029464 55 0 0 2007734016 32767 2007734031 32767 1031848544 55  
         1031836278 55 1034031064 55 2007733376 32767 2007734016 32767 2007733376 32767

Comment: With that change, your code worked for me. [This](http://pastebin.com/5xxg9Rxx) was the output I got.   What happens when you run your code with `cuda-memcheck` ? Are you running the exact code you have posted here?

Comment: yes I copied and pasted my code on here, with the exception of the change you suggested, it is exactly the same but it still isn't working. I launch cuda-memcheck as so: cuda-memcheck ./prog  and the end result is  ========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors    after printing the same out put.

Comment: The code with that change is correct.  I think you have some other problem with your CUDA setup which apparently is not easy to diagnose.  Can you run the cuda vectorAdd sample correctly on your setup?

Comment: ok I figured out the problem. I was using GeForce GTX 280 as my device.. I ssh to a node that had a device GeForce GTX 480 and now I'm getting the right results! thanks a ton man!!